# c# track timings of external request

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an application that will perform a bunch of user journeys, IE Signup, and gather the information on how quick that takes. This data will then be saved to a database and used for comparrison for the next build. This will eventually be made part of our CI process and automated.

What I would like to retrieve is the timings for each part of a request, like you would find in the network tab of the developer tools.

What I have so far is extremely simplistic, and I've been unable to find a way to gather more information about a request/series of requests.

```
public string AverageLoadTime(string url, int iterations = 10)
    {
        double totalTime = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string reply = client.DownloadString(url);

            timer.Stop();

            totalTime += timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        }

        return (totalTime / iterations).ToString();
    }
```

As you can see, currently it just gets the average of 10 page loads, using timers. Is there a way to get into the request itself and get a breakdown of the whole request? Then i'd turn it into a json object and then return that instead.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is currently just a PoC, it may not be the best way of doing it

Comment: There are a ton of APM tools that do this today.  This type of homegrown solution is tricky to get right and ultimately, you also want a backplane to store the data in.  While this is certainly possible, it isn't advisable, especially for production code.

Comment: You might want to consider something like MiniProfiler as a way to get started.

Comment: We already use New Relic for app performance monitoring. This is meant for a testing environment to test if there's any degredation in performance between builds

Comment: Could BrowserMob on Selenium be a way forward? https://www.adathedev.co.uk/2012/02/automating-web-performance-stats.html